# Voice search functionality in SearchView element in No action bar activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am having a SearchView in my activity which is blank activity( No Action bar ), i am not using Action Bar but i am placing SearchView alone in my layout XML. I am able to see many examples of implementing voice search with action bar, is there any way to implement search(include mic button in search view)of non action bar activity.